# Find the angle of inclination of each of the following lines.

Tags: calculus

The angle Alpha, $0 \leq \alpha \leq 180^{\circ}$, that a line makes with the positive $x$-axis is called the angle on inclination of the line.

$R(t) = (2,-6) + t(3,-4)$

Prove that the tangent of the angle of inclination is equal to the slope of the line

i don't know how to find the angle of inclination, or what equation to use... I wasn't able to find anything in videos, any hints?

Answer (score 0):

$m=−\dfrac{4}{3}$ and $R′(t)=(3,−4)$ the same pendient.